# Is it possible to apply a callback function to "new Date" using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I want to add 1 hour to every `Date` it created using prototype and now I got this:

```
Date.prototype.addOneHr = function (){
    this.setTime(this.getTime()+1*1000*60*60);
}
```

However, I have to call it every `new Date()`:

```
var date=new Date();
data.addOneHr();
```

It is very inconvenient and it gives me more *mess*. D:
So I am thinking that if there is a way to call `addOneHr()` every time I created a new `Date`, so that it won't give me headaches when editing the JavaScript.

Any solutions are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking, but you could make it a *little* better by altering your function slightly:

```
Date.prototype.addOneHr = function() {
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
  return this;
}
```

By having it return the object, you can write code like this:

```
var a_date = new Date().addOneHr();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend *against* modifying `Date`'s prototype to construct a date in the way you want it (this includes adding code to fire a callback function off when the `Date` is created).

Someone coming along and looking at your code will not immediately realize why all `new Date()`s are one hour in the future.

Instead, why not create a helper function that returns the Date you want and call *it* from everywhere instead:

```
function createDate() {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
    return now;
}
...

var date = createDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to change the behaviour of a class then you risk confusing anyone else who looks at your code and doesn't expect it to work so differently. To follow the classical OOP pattern you must, of course, create a descendent.

```
DatePlusOneHour = Object.Extend(Date, {
    getTime: function() {
        return Date.prototype.getTime.call(this) + 1000*60*60;
    }
});
```

You might need to override more functions than just `getTime` or perhaps you can override the constructor this way. I'm sure you understand what to do next.